# How to retrieve the special entries . and .. in a folder

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get a list of all the files and folders in a path, **including** the . and .. special entries; like the output from the DOS `DIR` command.

The documentation for scandir, listdir, and walk specifically state those two special entries are ignored. Glob doesn't say anything about them.  I tried:
`glob.glob('C:/TEMP/*.*')`
...and the returned list didn't include them.

Is there a function that **does** include them?  And, once I have them, how do I to get the last updated date/time stamp?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you need them for? You can get the attributes directly from the directory or its parent.

Comment: I am trying to mimic the DOS DIR command. DIR includes them, and shows a last updated date.

Comment: You could also add them manually to the output.

Comment: You're right, I could, but I was trying to not reinvent the wheel.